# How to clear a database on OpenShift

Tags: django, sqlite, openshift

I'm using Django with Sqlite3 on OpenShift and I need to reset my database (clear all the tables). How do I do that?

Comment: are you pushing the database to openshift repo along with the code?

Comment: I'm not pushing the database. But I'm not using a cartridge for it either. I think it's using the default sqlite3 backend that django ships with

Comment: No I've been pushing a lot of updates to my code. But that doesn't affect the database. And database entries can only be made from post requests while the server is online (running on openshift). And I have made changes to my schemas (via the model classes) but that doesn't seem to clear the database. How do I delete the database? I've only made pushes to the repo no pulls btw. Tried to give as much info

Comment: Do I have to do anything to the migrations for it to work again? Also please add that as an answer so I can accept it. I haven't tried it yet but I believe it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `flush` command to clear data from all the tables.

```
python manage.py flush
```

Note that this command will IRREVERSIBLY DESTROY all data currently in the  database.

To run a manage.py command in OpenShift,

- make sure you have ssh access to the repository.

### Step 1

#### Method 1: With RedHat Client

The easiest way is to install rhc,

You can install [rhc by following the official guide](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/client-tools.html)

After installation and configuration, run

```
rhc ssh <app name>
```

if everything gone correct, this will logs you into your app repo.

#### (or) Method 2: Without RedHat Client

Add your public key on [console settings](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/keys/new)

Copy the ssh command from the `Remote Access` section on console.

[image: login to repo with ssh openshift]

The command looks like,

```
ssh <some random string >@your-domain.rhcloud.com
```

Paste the command to a terminal window and press enter

### Step 2

Now navigate to your source directory, run

```
cd app-root/repo/
```

### Step 3

Now you are at the repo, where you can run your `manage.py` task

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

or

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

This is how you run a manage.py command in an repo.

make sure you don't share your keys.